# How to .off() click event all buttons in table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

I have bind all buttons click events as below. 
table's `id=dtappv`, `buttons' id=updatebtn` `function name = UpdateData(paravalue)`

```
    $(document).on("click", '#dtappv #updatebtn', function () {
        UpdateData($(this).attr("value"));
    });
```

This is inside the bootstrap modal popup and I want to off this click event in bootstrap modal close event as below but it didnt work.
Appreciate your advice!

```
 $('#modelUsers').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            //off click event
            $('#dtappv #updatebtn').off('click');
        });
```

Comment: since you are binding the events to `document` here `$(document).on("click"..` you need to `off` it on the `document` itself. Like `$(document).off("click"..` Also I would recommend you **Naming your click events** so that you have control on what events you remove. Like `.on('click.ModalButtons')` and later you can specifically **remove only this event and not all click events** by saying `off('click.ModalButtons')`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unbind while modal hides.

You can do this as follow

```
 $(document).off("click", '#dtappv #updatebtn');
 $(document).on("click", '#dtappv #updatebtn', function () {
     UpdateData($(this).attr("value"));
 });
```